# null controllability of linear wave equation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, sp.spectral-theory, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Consider the linear wave equation :

$$z_{tt}=\Delta z + k(x) z + h(t) , \; in \; \Omega\times (0,T)$$

Are there sufficient conditions on the functions $k(x)$ and $h(t)$ for which $(z,z_t)$ vanish  at $T$, i.e $z(T)=z_t(T)=0$.

Thanks!

Comment: Is is correct that $z=y$? 

Comment: Are you supposing by any chance that $h(t)$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $t=0$ or $T$?

Comment: This is an interesting question but the $z$-$y$ ambiguity needs resolution to allow orogress.  Waiting for the OP to speak up . . . 

Comment: I meant "progress", not "orogress" !

Comment: Looks like researcher edited his question.  Cool!

Comment: Concerning the question of Igor, we can suppose any constraint on the function "control" $h(t)$

Comment: Do you want $(z, z_t)$ to vanish at $t=T$ for *any* solution to this equation or, say, for the unique solution that satisfies $(z,z_t) = 0$ at $t = 0$?

Comment: Another thought: Given $k$ and $h$, solving the PDE backwards in time, there is a unique solution for $t \in [0,T]$ such that $(z,z_t) = 0$ at $t = T$. Therefore, given $k$ and $h$, there exists unique initial data $(z,z_t)$ at $t = 0$ for which the solution satisfies $(z,z_t) = 0$ at $t = T$.

Comment: I mean : For any initial state $(z(0),z_t(0))$, there exists a  time function $h(t)$ such that $z(T)=z_t(T)=0$. I think that this is true if $k(x)\ge 0.$ But, I m looking for constraints on $h(t$ but without condition on the sign of $k(x)!$  

Comment: @researcher:  what leads you to suspect such control can be obtained if $k(x) \geq 0$?

Comment: This is showed by  : A. Haraux, "An alternative functional approach to exact controllability of reversible systems", Portugallae Mathematca, Vol. 61 Fasc. 4,  Nova Série, (2004).


Comment: @researcher: Deane's point stands independent of the sign of $k(x)$. So, unique initial data $(z,z_t)$ at $t=0$ is guaranteed for any $k(x)$ and $h(t)$. What is suspicious about your claim in reply to Deane's comment is the existence of such $h(t)$ for _any_ given initial data set at $t=0$, provided that your notation means that $h(t)$ depends only on $t$. For example, what if $(z,z_t)$ have compact support at $t=0$? Then $h(t)$ will produce ripples arbitrarily far away that could not be canceled by the propagation of any part of the initial data.

Comment: For the Deane's response, I can not  see how to show this.  I know from (Haraux 2004), that some "geometric conditions on the domain $\Omega$" are needed with additional assumption on the sign of $k(x)$.